# A question about Gelfand triples

Tags: functional-analysis

In Gelfand triples we have a Hilbert space $(H,\left<\cdot,\cdot\right>)$ and a vector subspace $V\subseteq H$ such that $(V,\left|\cdot\right| )$ is a Banach space with $\overline{V}=H$ and continuous inclusion $i:V\to H$, $V\ni v\mapsto i(v)=v\in H$.  If $V$ were a Hilbert space instead a Banach space, then is it possible that $\text{dim}\,V\neq\text{dim}\,H$?

I'm asking about this because in Brezis, Functional Analysis, Remark 3, The triplet $V\subset H\subset V^*$,the author says:

The situation becomes more delicate if V turns out to be a Hilbert space with its own scalar product $((,))$ asssociated to the norm $\left\Vert \right\Vert $. We could, of course, identify $V$ and $V^*$ with the help of $(( , ))$. However, (9) ($V\subset H\simeq H^*\subset V^*$) becomes absurd.

Why is it absurd? I think it is absurd because we would have $V$ and $H$ isometrically isomorphic.  But this happens if and only if $V$ and $H$ have the same dimension (this is case of its $\textit{ very instructive}$ example).  But it could happen that $V$ and $H$ don't have the same dimension, and I don't know if this situation is really possible.

Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $V$ and $H$ *must* be isometrically isomorphic. Indeed, let $\dim V$ denote the cardinality of an orthonormal basis of $V$; $V\subset H$ implies that $\dim V\le\dim H$, but since the embedding is dense we also have $H\cong H^*\subset V^*\cong V$, and so $\dim H\le\dim V$.

This is not the issue, however. (Usually, $V$ and $H$ are both separable, so there is no question as to whether or not they are isometrically isomorphic.) The specific embedding is critical for applications, and so it no longer is useful to treat the spaces as the same. Indeed, if we identify $V$ and $V^*$, we would then have $V\subsetneq H\subsetneq V$, which is *clearly* absurd.

The prototypical example is this: let $\Omega\subset\mathbb R^d$ be a bounded domain and let $V=H^1_0(\Omega)$, $H=L^2(\Omega)$. Once we identify $H$ with its dual, we have effectively fixed the inner product in question, namely
$$\langle f,g\rangle_{L^2}=\int_\Omega f(x)g(x)\,dx.$$
Identifying $V$ with its dual would instead make use of the far more cumbersome inner product
$$\langle u,v\rangle_V=\int_\Omega uv+\nabla u\cdot\nabla v\, dx.$$
We do not want to do this; we would much prefer to somehow think of $V^*$ as "extending" the inner product on $H$. So considering the Gelfand triple $V\subset H\subset V^*$ means that we are identifying $V^*$ with some space of generalized functions on $\Omega$ containing $L^2(\Omega)$. If $u\in V$ and $f\in H$, then $f\in V^*$ and so $f$ acts on $u$ via
$$\langle f,u\rangle_{V^*,V}=\langle f,u\rangle_{L^2}=\int fu\,dx.$$
If $F\in V^*\setminus H$, we might still write $\langle F,u\rangle_{V,V^*}=\int Fu\,dx$, even though this no longer really means what it usually does. The advantage comes when we start looking at differential operators, as things like integration by parts still work. For an example, define the operator $\Delta:V\to V^*$ by
$$\langle\Delta u,v\rangle_{V^*,V}:=-\int\nabla u\cdot\nabla v\,dx.$$
If $u\in C^\infty_c(\Omega)$, a simple integration by parts shows that this agrees with our usual definition of the Laplacian, and with our convention above we might still write
$$-\int\nabla u\cdot\nabla v=\int(\Delta u)v.$$
Additionally, when one starts studying second-order linear parabolic equations, the natural space of solutions is the set of $u\in L^2((0,T);V)$ with weak derivative $u'\in L^2((0,T);V^*)$. Think of how little sense all this would make if we had originally identified $V$ with $V^*$.